# json data using PHP looks like corrupted

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get JSON data from https://offer-1.betting.superbet.pl/matches/getMatchesByIds?matchIds=2885636

I'm using this code in PHP:

```
$link = "https://offer-1.betting.superbet.pl/matches/getMatchesByIds?matchIds=2885636";
$json = file_get_contents($link);
$json_data = json_decode($json);
```

but

```
var_dump($json_data);
```

returns NULL

Saving this file using file_put_contents(); file gives me a file that looks something like this:

```
xÚĚ˝ÍŽ\I’.ö*ƒ\ö”nżnĆĄA@.p—-ü·§4ŐĹFUM.Fó\ÚëÉ„dć9‘á<Af{î†?ÁĚä÷ą›ŮgînnţOă·ß>ýöôq–_~?=őňGů§_ź>ţÇSűôëż}úĺ—ńŰÓÇ§ż”?ÚżŚßź~zúËřă_>ő§ŹOüźź?ý_ţÇ?őíźÚ§żüő·ńűď?úőéăżýŰřéó÷m˙úń‰ÜŐŘžţóóňôńź˙ăé/??}üňůOOŮ~*%J€D˙€ö‘ÓÇ”ž~zúăg|úřdxů=}|RŐí/iO5B~zúů×öŰřËřőŹęOłädA?=}šÇ˙â÷źź>ęOOíç§ŹčyűQOMä§§ß?=}D
```

I also tried using curl, but it doesn't work as well:

```
$link = "https://offer-1.betting.superbet.pl/matches/getMatchesByIds?
matchIds=2885636";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

What am I forgeting about?

Comment: There are many questions about JSON data on PHP, have you tried to find a similar issue on StackOverflow already?

Comment: this looks like some encoding issue, you will be better off to implement this with curl, which will allow you to read the headers too. You need to find out what encoding you are receiving and then convert the response to the encoding of your server before you call the `json_decode()` function.

Comment: The result might be archived in some way and you might have to unpack it.

Comment: Ofc I was trying to find similar issue, no only here but I failed.
The weird part (for me) is that when U use this json link in browser it gives You a clear json file that U can normally save, but using in PHP doesnt work.

Comment: @UrukMorg ... a browser is not useful, xept maybe Firefox (try your URL) ... you would have seen the data structure, the headers, the raw data, and pretty print. Still, beware of tools that want to make your life easy and comfy, they tend to alter reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$link = "https://offer-1.betting.superbet.pl/matches/getMatchesByIds?matchIds=2885636";
// Output is deflate-compressed. Use gzuncompress() to unpack.
$json = gzuncompress(file_get_contents($link));
$json_data = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're very welcome. If you found my answer helpful, then please consider marking it as the accepted answer :).